# Effects of Re-coding a regression

Tags: regression, modeling, least-squares, spatial

I have been analysing a number of likert scale variables using spatial auto-regressive models. However, my question I think can be applied to an OLS model.

After analyzing the data I obtained some odd coefficients, which led me to realize that some of the variables were coded inversely. That is, 1 was very important and the highest number was not very important. So I re-coded the response so that the larger the number the more important it is. I had assumed that this would only change the coefficients direction, and maybe slightly effect the magnitude, however I have received some dramatically different results.

My question is then: Should I have expected to see such a dramatic change in the results? Or am I correct in being suspicious of my re-coding?

Comment: There's not enough information. Were these coded as factors? How were these variables used in the model? Were there interactions?

Comment: My Apologies. No, as I stated they were scales, and treated as numeric values.The re-coded variable is the response - there is no change to the model or interactions in the model.

Comment: Then I am not sure how it would happen in OLS. Can you be more specific about the effects?

Comment: What do you mean by effects? I am really looking for an answer to the question: If you reverse the scale of a response, should you expect opposite results? If you are saying that this is the case, I would think that I've done something wrong whilst re-coding my response.

Comment: I believe the only thing that should happen to coefficient estimates and standard errors (besides the sign changes you anticipate) is that you change the constant.

Comment: Ah yes and of course the constant. But thank-you. This confirms that I have done something else wrong. If you would like to form that as an answer I will accept it :) Thank-you for your advice, and again sorry for not being specific enough initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in OLS, flipping the direction ($x_j^* = k-x_j$) of an ordinary explanatory variable (/predictor) that isn't involved in any interactions should only change its sign and the coefficient of the constant (along with things those directly affect, like the sign of the t-ratio for the $j$-th variable and the constant's t-ratio and p-value).

If you let $\beta^*_j =-\beta_j$ and $\beta_0^* = \beta_0+\beta_j k$ then you can see exactly the same fit is obtained (which must therefore minimize the sum of squares).

(If that's not convincing, there are a few ways of coming at it to see that nothing else can change, but I'd probably do it in terms of Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.)

We can see this is what happens with an example done in R. "cars" is a data set containing speed and stopping distance of cars in the 1920s (`speed` and `dist` respectively; below I will cut out a few lines of output that we don't care about here):

```
cars2 <- cars                # taking a copy to play with
cars2$sp2 <- cars2$speed^2   # add speed^2 as a second variable

head(cars2)                  # examine the first few rows
  speed dist sp2
1     4    2  16
2     4   10  16
3     7    4  49
4     7   22  49
5     8   16  64
6     9   10  81
```

Everything looks good. Now let's fit the original model.

```
summary(lm(dist~speed+sp2,cars2))               # original model

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  2.47014   14.81716   0.167    0.868 
speed        0.91329    2.03422   0.449    0.656
sp2          0.09996    0.06597   1.515    0.136

Residual standard error: 15.18 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6673,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6532 
F-statistic: 47.14 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 5.852e-12
```

Now flip some variables:

```
summary(lm(dist~I(10-speed)+sp2,cars2))         # flip first variable

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   11.60301    7.36936   1.574    0.122
I(10 - speed) -0.91329    2.03422  -0.449    0.656
sp2            0.09996    0.06597   1.515    0.136

Residual standard error: 15.18 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6673,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6532 
F-statistic: 47.14 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 5.852e-12

summary(lm(dist~speed+I(16-sp2),cars2))           # flip second variable

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  4.06949   15.76686   0.258    0.797
speed        0.91329    2.03422   0.449    0.656
I(16 - sp2) -0.09996    0.06597  -1.515    0.136

Residual standard error: 15.18 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6673,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6532 
F-statistic: 47.14 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 5.852e-12
```

As expected, aside from the effect on the constant, the only things that changed were the flipping of the sign of the coefficient and t-statistic for the variable that was flipped around.